# Fragment finalize not called

Tags: android

```
public void onDestroy() {
}
protected void finalize() {
}
```

Does finalize not always get called for fragments?

What about the fields that are inside of the fragment instance? Must I set them to null in `onDestroy` so that they are reclaimed?

Comment: For the most part, don't worry about `finalize()` with Android and in particular the main Android components (Activity, Fragment, Service etc etc). The OS is designed to be very efficient when it comes to cleaning up resources and garbage collection and such. This stuff is all done behind the scenes when the OS determines a particular object is no longer needed.

Comment: I'm trying to diagnose a memory spike in my app though. So...I need to know when objects are reclaimed.

Comment: I would have the best way to do that would be to use the various Android SDK tools.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the finalize method is called by the garbage collector and cannot be relied upon to be called at a given time.

These posts may give you more insight:

- [How does finalize() work in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556827/how-does-finalize-work-in-java)
- [When is the finalize() method called in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506488/java-finalize-method-call)

I tend to do my cleanup in onPause or onDestroy.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "cleanup" I'm not sure I'd recommend doing much in onPause bearing in mind the onPause -> onResume -> onPause cycle is the tightest of an Activity or Fragment life-cycle.